# Is Quote Necessary when creating order Programatically

Tags: magento2, orders, quote

I have integrated a third party API in which I have to create order to maintain sync from both the stores.

My question is do I have to create quote first and then order? Is it necessary to create quote? As I don't see any reason for creating it?

Can I create an order directly?

Answer (score 0):

Magento stores all its Order Data in  `sales_flat_order` table which has a **foreign key** column `quote_id` which is connected to quote table.

Magento follows the flow add to cart and create order for same .

So to take care a internal checks you have to create a quotes for placing order.